# Restart HTTP task in Domino after infinite loop in SSJS causes process to hang

Tags: ibm-domino

If a developer writes some code with an infinite loop in SSJS the HTTP task will eventually use close to 100% of the CPU. I have not found a way to restart just the http task without restarting the server.

I can't kill the task and restart the task as it waits for a specific thread to clear. The thread ID is visible if that is of any value.

I can't restart the server as it will wait for the HTTP task to shut off.

I am thinking that I can kill everything at the OS level and restart from there but I am not sure if that is possible.

Can anyone provide some instructions on how resolve this problem without restarting the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to resolve such a problem.

IBM has published [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21497126) about the issue.

> There is currently no way to limit the execution time of an HTTP
>   thread run by a Domino web server, and there is no way to cleanly stop
>   such a thread.